Power automate not finding an a tag identified by an id
I have a website that I'm trying to get data from.  I've got the power automate code that logs in and brings up a person.  The persons name is a hyperlink that you click on to find out more details.  I cannaot get power sutomate to click on the link.  The HTML is
<td style="width:150px;">
<a onclick="javascript:location.replace('/searchAction.aspx?Action=patientupdate&amp;patID=57779&amp;patN=Ms%2bGayle%2bAdam&amp;patBID=8&amp;patBN=Cumnock');SetTimer();return false;DeleteCookie(&quot;metspex&quot;,&quot;/&quot;);return false;" id="gridViewPatients_ctl02_PxDetails" title="Patient Details" href="javascript:__doPostBack('gridViewPatients$ctl02$PxDetails','')" style="display:inline-block;width:150px;">Ms Joan Adam</a>
</td>  

I have set power automate up to click on the link - click link on webpage - using
ELements->anchor->Patient details->id = gridViewPatients_ctl02_PxDetails
but if always fails with error of unable to find the anchor to click on.
Element with selector 'a[Id="gridViewPatients_ct102_PxDetails"] not found
Worth noting that the anchor is put on the page via ajax and the browser is firefox.

I suspect the mentioned element was created dynamically, which could be the reason for why it was not detected by the recorder. However, I'm not certain about the actual root cause, so create a fiddle page and share the link to help reproduce the issue.
